# Power Query - extracting only visible/filtered cells from an excel file

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I working on consolidating 200 excel files into one master file for different sources. The format is mostly the same but the problem with these files is they are filtered and the requirement is only to consolidate the visible cells - I was looking to do this through power query but i can't find a way to extract only the visible cells or even get the filter information. Anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The visibilty of a row/column is only a property of the Excel worksheet. Inside Excel its possible to write a macro which is setting a flag 0/1 in every row/column if it is visible or not. After that filtering with powerquery is easy.

To keep the source files unchanged, I would write a macro doing the following steps:

1. create a temp-copy of each workbook in a separate folder
2. Insert the first row / colum in the worksheet as new
3. set the visibility flags in this header rows/columns
4. save the workbook as excel-file or csv

Comment: Thanks for point me in the right direct i've started code and will build on it..                                                                                                    ' ' 'Set sht = Worksheets("SCOPE_LS")

sht.Columns("A:A").Insert

sht.Range("A3").Value2 = "Hidden 1 or 0"

Set Rge = sht.Range("A4:A" & sht.UsedRange.Rows.Count)

For Each r In Rge

    If r.Rows.Hidden = True And Not IsEmpty(sht.Range("B" & r.Row).Value2) Then
        r.Value2 = "1"
        Else
        r.Value2 = "0"
    End If
Next r '

Answer (score 3):

In the case that you can modify the source files, put a new column in each table and use the function [AGGREGATE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43b9278e-6aa7-4f17-92b6-e19993fa26df?omkt=en-US&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US), which calculates, if the row is hidden or not.

```
=AGGREGATE(3, 5, [@columnX])
```

In Power Query you can then use this new column and put a filter on it, in order to keep the visible rows.

Comment: Great! I was looking for a solution without macros! Thanks a lot!